# using kotest FreeSpec on multiplatform module

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotest

I looks like there's no native module with `io.kotest.core.spec.style.FreeSpec`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this build.gradle.kts from the Kotest repo](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/kotest-framework/kotest-framework-api/build.gradle.kts), the only available targets are JVM and JS. I also found an [issue](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1743) with some discussion about K/N support.